# SharePoint 2013 list all tasks created by me

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, tasks, task-list

A manager would like to have a list of all the tasks he has created instead of all the tasks assigned to him. Is there an out of the box way to do this?

We are running Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating a view with a filter the is `Created By is equal to [Me]`. This is dynamic and will show all tasks for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest Using the Core Search Web Part.

Create a new page.

Add webpart to page -> search-> core result web part.
Edit the web part
Edit query

Setup a query that is something like:-

ContentTypeId:0x108* AND Author:"[insert manager display name]"

You'll probably want to only show future tasks but I'll leave that for you to try and sort out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Content Search Query Web Part
You can construct the query by selecting the Task Content type which is ContentTypeId:0x0108*

[image]

and then click on **REFINERS**

go to Display Author and select the appropriate user to show the task results created by that user.

[image]

Let me know if this solutions works for you.