# Global view of all all tasks (sps 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server, task-list

Is it possible to get a list of all (open) tasks for a website collection?

I checked [Sharepoint 2013 task list of all tasks created](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144537/sharepoint-2013-task-list-of-all-tasks-created) already but this approach isn't exactly what we need. For each project we create a project site under a specifc websitecollection "projects". Our project portfolio managers needs a list of all tasks of all projects. Even when he *hasn't created the task by himself* (that's the requirement, the solution above can't solve).

The ideal solution would be a hierarchical list where the projects are the parents and the tasks are the child items.

Comment: Search should work as described in that post, you simply would not include the refiner. It would pull back all tasks regardless of who it is assigned to that they have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric mentioned in the comment already, you can do it using method described in the link. Instead filtering by user, you'll have to filter by path to limit results to one site collection.

Another solution is to use *Content Query WebPart* (it requires *SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* site collection feature to be activated). You can use it to aggregate all tasks in site collection and can group results by site.

Content Query has an adventage because data is always fresh (search requires crawling). Search is better when you need to aggregate tasks from more than one site collection.

Comment: The Content Query WebPart doesn't work for us, as we can't setup the search path. The webpage with the webpart is in another site collection as the project sites. When using the search, we get the results. Only thing we have to solve is the representation of the search results. A plain list isn't really management-friendly :)